# Unable to use BubbleIconFactory in Google map utils

Tags: android, google-maps

Unable to use The new BubbleIconFactory its giving deprecated

dependency Gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}


// want to use this 
BubbleIconFactory bubbleIconFactory = new BubbleIconFactory(this);
```

Answer (score 13):

`BubbleIconFactory` is deprecated. You can use `IconGenerator` instead:

```
IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon("Your text here")))
    .position(new LatLng(40, -4))
    .anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());

mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

[Here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/IconGeneratorDemoActivity.java) you can find the official demo activity.

Comment: No, i was using the same before but as the map posses many markers , this generates in OOM issue

Comment: you save my day

Answer (score 1):

`BubbleIconFactory` is deprecated in Java. and yes as @antonio mentioned, use `IconGenerator`.

Dependency: `implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'`

In Java

```
    IconGenerator iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
    // You can style icon using the IconGenerator.STYLE_BLUE
    iconGenerator.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_BLUE);

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconGenerator.makeIcon("Your text here");))
            .position(new LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085))  // Sydney, Australia
            .anchor(iconGenerator.getAnchorU(), iconGenerator.getAnchorV());
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

In Kotlin

```
   val iconGenerator = IconGenerator(this)
    // You can style icon using the IconGenerator.STYLE_BLUE 
    iconGenerator.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_GREEN)
    
   
    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
     
 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconGenerator.makeIcon("Text here")))
        .position(LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085)) // Sydney, Australia
        .anchor(iconGenerator.anchorU, iconGenerator.anchorV)
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
```